# Sum multiple possible values in VLOOKUP on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have a table with several fields in Google Spreadsheet. Three of the are called `Code`, `Price` and `Quantity`.

I made an "special hidden" column to show the `PRODUCT()` of `Price` and `Quantity` (called `SubTotal`).

In another place I have a another little table with two fields: `Code` and `Total`.

I want to populate `Total` with the `SUM()` of every `Subtotal` with the same `Code`.

So I made a function like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B4;I5:M17;5;false)
```

to get the Subtotal and it works, but only for one item.
The items on Code can be repeated so I want the SUM() of every subtotal, so I tried with:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B3;I5:M17;5;false)))
```

but returns the same than the first one, only 1 item, the first one that founds.

I'm expecting get the `SUM()` of every item in subtotal by code, but also I want to know if I can do this without using the column `SubTotal`, like made the product inside the formula, which is something I could not do also.

Comment: You can use the function filter =SUM(FILTER(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used FILTER:

```
=SUM(FILTER($M$5:$M$20;$I$5:$I$20=$B3))
```